# cannot be resolved () Загрузка в поле JLabel String_a

Tags: java

Вкратце такое дело. Начал изучать Java по [видеокурсу](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnV3K-pmuXwg9S6YhNnWvOG3PXkSaVPsN): 
дойдя до [урока 167](https://youtu.be/uT8jaTMap50), столкнулся с вот такой проблемой как загрузить в компонент графического интерфейса элементы. Пишем тренажер клавиатуры, (в уроках используют NetBeans я использую Eclipse,  коды при создании JFrame form  отличаются, но пока справлялся). 
Имеем три класса:

- `MainWindow` (import  не указал)
- `ExerciseGUI` (import  не указал)
- `Lessons`

---

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    private ExerciseGUI exercise;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private void exit() { 
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Do you really want to exit?", "Information", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE );
        if(result != JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private void centered() { 
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension frameSize = this.getSize();
        if(frameSize.height > screenSize.height) {
            frameSize.height = screenSize.height;
        }
        if(frameSize.width > screenSize.width) {
            frameSize.width = screenSize.width;
        }

        this.setLocation((screenSize.width - frameSize.width) / 2 ,(screenSize.height - frameSize.height) / 2);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                exit();
            }
        });

        this.setTitle("Название программы"); 
        this.setSize(500, 400); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.centered(); 

        exercise = new ExerciseGUI();
        exercise.pack();
        exercise.validate();
        exercise.reveal(new Lessons("Lessons 1", "Please type" , "fjkd fkll jklh assdf"));
        exercise.setResizable(true);
        exercise.setVisible(true);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu file_name = new JMenu("File");
        file_name.setMnemonic('F');
        menuBar.add(file_name);

        JMenuItem file_exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        file_exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                exit();
            }
        });

        file_name.add(file_exit);

        JMenu help_menu = new JMenu("Help");
        help_menu.setMnemonic('H');
        menuBar.add(help_menu);

        JMenuItem help_about = new JMenuItem("About");
        help_about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Under Construction...", "Разработка", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        help_menu.add(help_about);

        JMenuItem help_on_typist = new JMenuItem("Help");
        help_on_typist.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Under Construction...", "Думаем ещё", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        help_menu.add(help_on_typist);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        contentPane.add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        desktopPane.add(exercise); 
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ExerciseGUI extends JInternalFrame {

    private Lessons lessons;
    public void reveal (Lessons lessons) {
        this.lessons = lessons; 
        // выдает ошибку title_label cannot be resolved
        title_label.setText(lessons.get_title()); 
        descr_label.setText(lessons.get_instructions());//cannot be resolved
        reference_text_area.setText(lessons.get_text());//cannot be resolved
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ExerciseGUI frame = new ExerciseGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ExerciseGUI() {
        setResizable(true);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JPanel top_panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(top_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
        top_panel.add(toolbar);
        JButton restart_button = new JButton("Restart");
        toolbar.add(restart_button);
        JToggleButton pause_button = new JToggleButton("Pause");
        toolbar.add(pause_button);
        JPanel label_panel = new JPanel();
        top_panel.add(label_panel);
        JLabel title_label = new JLabel("title");
        label_panel.add(title_label);
        JLabel descr_label = new JLabel("");
        label_panel.add(descr_label);
        JPanel text_panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(text_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        text_panel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
        JSplitPane dril_pane = new JSplitPane();
        dril_pane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        text_panel.add(dril_pane, "name_11473649550263");
        JTextArea reference_text_area = new JTextArea();
        dril_pane.setLeftComponent(reference_text_area);
        JTextArea entry_text_area = new JTextArea();
        dril_pane.setRightComponent(entry_text_area);
        JPanel status_panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(status_panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Lessons {
    private String title;
    private String instructions;
    private String text;
    public Lessons (String title, String instructions, String text) {

        this.title = title;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String get_title() {

        if (title !=null) return title;
        else return "Title";
    }

    public String get_instructions() {

        if (instructions !=null) return instructions;
        else return "Instructions";
    }

    public String get_text() {

        if (text !=null) return text;
        else return "Text";
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

```
private Lessons lessons;
private JLabel title_label;
private JLabel descr_label;
private JTextArea reference_text_area;
public void reveal (Lessons lessons) {
    this.lessons = lessons; 
    title_label.setText(lessons.get_title());
    descr_label.setText(lessons.get_instructions());
    reference_text_area.setText(lessons.get_text());
}
```

Вот так дописал...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А вы поправили конструктор? или только добавили поля класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы видимо не понимаете концепцию полей класса и область видимости переменных, попробуйте почитать про это или пересмотрите уроки. В этом конкретном случае метод reveal ничего не знаешь про переменные с именем title_label, descr_label, reference_text_area. Для того чтобы он про них узнал и они ссылались на правильный объект, вам необходимо объявить их как поля класса, что-такое:

```
public class ExerciseGUI extends JInternalFrame {

    private Lessons lessons;
    private JLabel title_label;
    private JLabel descr_label;
    private JTextArea reference_text_area;
    ...     

    public ExerciseGUI() {
        ...
        title_label = new JLabel("title");
        descr_label = new JLabel("");
        ...
    }    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, сделал как Вы посоветовали, ошибки ушли, но при запуске вот такие ругательства: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ExerciseGUI.reveal(ExerciseGUI.java:27)
 at MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:83)
 at MainWindow$1.run(MainWindow.java:55)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 ... (ещё дальше есть)

Comment: @Evgeny очевидно, что что-то там null, что именно я не знаю, вы конструктор тоже обновили?

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, ваш ответ очень помог, я все исправил. Запустил и даже заработало как и ожидалось:)